# cannot assign php var to js var

Tags: javascript, php

I have a PHP variable and I want to assign it's value to JS var, but it returns as " " or NaN if I use parseInt()

Here is the code:
PHP:

```
$souls=mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($db,"SELECT Souls FROM Accounts WHERE Username='$username'"));
$souls_value=$souls['Souls'];
```

JS:

```
var souls=parseInt("<?php echo $souls_value; ?>");
```

I've tried writing

```
var souls=<?php echo $souls_value; ?>;
```

But then script crashes completely and all functions won't work.

Comment: Where exactly is that JS? Are you sure the PHP in there is being parsed and `$souls_value` is actually set?

Comment: PHP part is working perfectly. I tried it

Comment: well I tried to use this $souls_value and print it in span. It works. Previously I was using <?php echo $souls['Souls']?> in the span and it worked too.

Comment: Look at the source code when you load the page - what do you see?

Comment: you mean errors Kingkero?

Comment: Do a `var_dump($souls_value)`. My assumption here is that you'll find that `$souls_value` is an array of records, so in order to perform the dereference you're doing you need to do `$souls[0]['souls_value']`.. and that's assuming it's returning at least one record (it mightn't be). Do you have your error reporting enabled? Add `error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT); ini_set('display_errors', true);`. Also, your SQL injection is showing - you should validate/escape your `$username` var, or even better use prepared statements.

Comment: Is all this in one file? Or do you have the JS in a separate file?
Can you do a var_dump() of the $souls_value just before you try to echo it?
What do you mean "then script crashes completely"? Are there error messages?

Comment: No, JS and HTML (there is PHP code) are not in one file.
By saying "script crashes completely" I mean that all functions stop working and even simple buttons stop working

Comment: If the JS is not in the same file as the PHP, then you most likely don't have access to the PHP variables.
And if there are no error messages, you need to turn on error reporting from PHP and start looking at the console for JS errors in your browser.

Comment: is there any way to link PHP and JS files? @Thorbear

Comment: Not really. To PHP, JavaScript is just text, and to JavaScript PHP doesn't exist. If you want to "link" them, the JS will need to be a part of the output from PHP in some way.

Comment: I put it in one file. works fine. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in one file if `$souls_value` is not an array:

PHP

```
$souls=mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($db,"SELECT Souls FROM Accounts WHERE Username='$username'"));
$souls_value=$souls['Souls'];
```

JS

```
var souls = '<?php echo $souls_value; ?>';
alert(souls);
```

Comment: it works. alerts "10000" as it supposed to.
this may be the solution for my question. But will I be able to use this war from my .js file?